# PHP write to file - XML Parsing Error: no root element found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to send a POST request with JSON data to a PHP file, and have the PHP file write the data to another file.

```js
var json = JSON.stringify(blogObj);

$.post("addBlog.php", { json: json }, function(data, status) {
  alert("Sent!");
});
```

```php
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("blog.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = $_POST["json"];
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Whenever the POST request is sent, I get the following error in the console

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found
>       Location: http://localhost/addBlog.php
>       Line Number 6, Column 3:

The file being written to has the correct permissions

Comment: Try read the data with `$input_data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");`

Comment: @PKeidel I still get the same error. Is this indicative of something?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from jQuery. I would assume that it tries to parse the response as an XML request.

Another problem is that `$_POST["json"]` is an array and can't be written straight to a file.

Try the following:

```
$.post("ajax.php", {json: {test: 1, test2: 2, huhu: "du da"}}, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, "json"); // <- parse response as JSON instead of XML
```

And for ajax.php:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("/tmp/storage.log", json_encode($_POST["json"])."\n", FILE_APPEND);
echo json_encode(['status' => 'ok']);
```